# get post thumbnail image in wordpress and display in 3 coulmn

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to display one particular category posts as a three column layout The problem I have is I am not sure how I can use for or forwach to loop the display of each post thumbnail so whn it comes more than three I can use one_thrid_last.  css class.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (is_category('actress-gallery') ):?>
<?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>     
<div class="one_fourth_last">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php   echo $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , 'thumbnail' );   ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'tie' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </a>
    </div><!-- post-thumbnail /-->

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: didnt get you question ?

Comment: The above code will display the thumbnail of all the posts of that category in vertial order, all I wanted is the images to be displayed as 3 images per row... like a grid... Thanks

Comment: means show 3 images in first row and then shift to next row ? and so on ?

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i want

Comment: this is a css issue rather make a div give it some fix width inside it run your loop each loop should output your image wrapped in another div now style both ... give width accordingly for example give outer div width of 800px and inner divs width of 250px.

Comment: I made all those css, what I am not aware of doing is to run the content in the loop... using the if statement,

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:800px; height:auto;">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <div class="image-wrapper" style=" width:250px; height:300px;" >
            <?php the_title();?>
            <?php the_content();?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, unforutnately it dose something else than expected, All I wanted to do is to pass 1 image at a time to the loop inside the div class one third and when it is 3 per row Ihave to pass it to the div one third last.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:750px; height:700px;">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<div style="width:250px; height:300px;" >
   <?php the_title();?>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
 <?php } endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$count` variable and check for the 3rd thumbnail.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $count = 1; ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <?php if ($count % 3 == 0) : ?>
                <div class = "one_third_last">
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class = "other_class">
            <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php the_title();?>
                    <?php the_content();?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```